# what is complex in this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, complexity-theory

I have this action in my rails controler,

```
 def step_submit
   validate_user()
   @owning = @user.create_user_car_transaction(Variant.find(params[:variant]),   params[:details], params[:address], params[:somethin1])
   Contact.user_contact(current_user, params[:contact]) if @user.contact.nil?
   redirect_to "/next_step"
end
```

I use codeClimate to check the quality of the code..

it shows this action's complexity ~ 30 .. 
I actually broke a really huge method into this.. how can i still reduce this complexity?

these are the different methods the action calls

```
def self.user_contact(user, contact_hash = nil)
 contact = user.contact || user.create_contact()
 contact.update_attributes(contact_hash) if contact_hash.present?
 contact
end

def validate_user
 if params[:user] && current_user.nil?
   user = User.create(params[:user])
   sign_in user
 end
end

def create_user_car_transaction(car, details_hash, address_hash, coupon_hash = nil)
 transaction = self.transactions.create()

 car.transaction_item = transaction.transaction_items.create()
 car.save

 payment_hash = details_hash
 payment_hash.merge!(address_hash)
 payment = transaction.create_payment(payment_hash)

 transaction.update_attributes(:status=>"1") if transaction.status.nil?

 transaction
end
```

Comment: you have to add more information about the different methods you call in this action.. create_user_car_transaction -> what does this method? user_contact -> what does this method? you do not have much lines of code..but behind your methods could be the complexity. please post your methods also..

Comment: hi, i have edited the question showing the methods I'm calling in this action.

Comment: It seems that your methods do a lot of stuff ;-). Try to benchmark each method and you will se which one causes the performance issues..